# Swiper, swiper-slide background color is not correct

Tags: swiper.js

I want these three slide background color take turns.

like this: green(1) -> orange(2) -> green(3) - orange(1)...

But current behaviour is not as expected.

How can I fix this?

```js
window.onload = function() {

  const defaultOptions = {
    speed: 2000,
    autoplay: true,
    spaceBetween: 4,
    direction: 'vertical',
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    watchSlidesVisibility: true
  };

  const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', defaultOptions)
}
```

```css
.swiper-container{
    height: 52px;
  }

  .swiper-slide{
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: 26px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/Swiper/3.4.2/js/swiper.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.staticfile.org/Swiper/3.4.2/css/swiper.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='swiper-container'>
  <div class='swiper-wrapper'>
    <div class='swiper-slide' style='background: green'>message 1</div>
    <div class='swiper-slide' style='background: orange'>message 2</div>
    <div class='swiper-slide' style='background: green'>message 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have loop: true, so it adds clones and that's why you have this issue! and clones usually extra slide before and after, in this case, extra green before and extra green after!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the background color on alternate slides but the real trick is toggling them when the duplicate slides are regenerated for the looping functionality.

I've modified your supplied code with a variable to track progress and a test condition when the slides begin to change.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var lastIndex = 0;

  const defaultOptions = {
    speed: 2000,
    autoplay: true,
    spaceBetween: 4,
    direction: 'vertical',
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    watchSlidesVisibility: true,
    onSlideNextStart: function(swiperObj) {
      if ( swiperObj.activeIndex < lastIndex ) {
        swiperObj.container[0].classList.toggle('alt-bg');
      }
      lastIndex = swiperObj.activeIndex;
    }
  };

  const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', defaultOptions)
}
```

```css
.swiper-container{
    height: 52px;
  }

  .swiper-slide{
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: 26px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background: green;
  }

  .swiper-slide:nth-child(2n+1){
    background: orange;
  }

  .alt-bg .swiper-slide{
    background: orange;
  }
  .alt-bg .swiper-slide:nth-child(2n+1){
    background: green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/Swiper/3.4.2/js/swiper.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.staticfile.org/Swiper/3.4.2/css/swiper.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='swiper-container'>
  <div class='swiper-wrapper'>
    <div class='swiper-slide'>message 1</div>
    <div class='swiper-slide'>message 2</div>
    <div class='swiper-slide'>message 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```